# Memory Consumption by an app - WIndows phone 8.1 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm currently working in Web Scraping based windows phone 8.1 version. And I want this app to consume very low memory space. This is why I need to check how much memory it's taking when running. I can't find the option to see this memory log. Anyone has any idea how this can be done?

Comment: are you using VS 2013?

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2013 there is a powerful tool for monitoring CPU, Memory usage and UI responsiveness go to `Debug--->Performance and diagnostics`. Select memory usage ans start diagnostics. See Below images.

[image]
[image]

**Another option is to use `windows phone developer Power tools 8.1` see below image** see below image
[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The emulator in many cases may behave not as a real device. I'd recommend using Release version and test on a real device.
If you have Windows Phone 10 device, you may consider enabling the Device portal and monitoring your app performance and memory usage there:
http://mspoweruser.com/new-device-portal-in-windows-10-mobile-makes-it-super-easy-to-sideload-apps-pictures/
It even supports REST API in case you want to make some test automation.